# Regex Expression in Notepad ++ (Replacing value)

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm trying to replace a statement that has this pattern:

**readonly="if(xxxx.x_DATE lt yyyy.y_yyyyy,True,False)"**

where "DATE" in the statement are dynamic (vary in the file, i.e. 0101, 0102, 0103 etc)

I have tried to do research on this but the answers vary between posts. I'm a novice notepad++ user so please bear with my silliness.

Thanks

Comment: it's not clear from your answer what exactly you want to do. Do you want to replace the whole line, or only part of it? Also a few examples would be very useful.

Comment: What are you trying to replace it with? What should to desired output look like?

Answer (score 0):

- Open the find and replace dialogue box <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- In 'Find what' enter: `readonly="if\(xxxx\.x_\d{4} lt yyyy.y_yyyyy,True,False\)"`
- In 'Replace with' enter your desired replacement value
- Make sure to select `Regular expression`
- Click on 'Replace All'

Please note that in the first screen I changed a few values to match the samples you gave, but left the 3rd as 'DATE'. Because I used `\d{4}` it mathes only those lines with numbers.

You can use capture groups if you need to reuse some of the data in the strings you are replacing.

[image]

[image]

[image]